# Unable to require express route file

Tags: node.js, express

This is my code in server.js

```
app.use( 'project', require( 'routers/project-route' )() );
```

I have a folder in the project directory called `routers` and inside it has `project-route.js` file

However when i tried running the server, i got `Cannot find module 'routers/project-route'`

This is my `project-route.js` file

```
module.exports = function( ) {
    var express = require( "express" )
      , router = express.Router()
      , controller = require( '../controllers/project-controller' );

    router.route( '/' )
        .get({
            res.send('hello')
        })
        .post( controller.create );

   router.route( '/:id' )
       .get( controller.get )
       .put( controller.update )
       .delete( controller.delete );  

   return router;
};
```

Comment: Try `app.use('project', require( './routers/project-route' )())`. Node expects the path to be relative there I believe, so prepend the `./` to your path. Just FYI, `require()` is blocking and should be called at the beginning of your app, not in a route handler like you have it.

Comment: @Nocturno So I require on top of modules.export?

Comment: When you require modules at the beginning of **server.js** like `var express = require('express')`, that's when you should require your routes too `var projectRoute = require('./routers/project-route')`. Then later in **server.js** you can call `app.use('project', projectRoute')`. Keep in mind that this isn't why you're getting that error. I believe that error is because you were missing the ./ in your path.